# Set the highest priced variation as default in WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I have a lots of products with variations in my WooCommerce installation.
None of them are pre-selected as default when user browses to any product page.

Manually selecting them would be a tedious job. Additionally, new products and variations are imported automatically on a daily basis using an SQL script.

I would like to have pre-selected product variation with the highest price for any user that browses to any product page which has variable product.

How can that be done?

Comment: you do the importation with PHP code ?

Comment: :) yes definitely thats an option. The other option is to run an sql command. Does anyone have a sample of such script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update - 2023 *(code simplification and optimization)*

Here it is an automated solution, that will do the job one time, each time a variable product is called/browse by a customer.

The variable product will be updated with a default variation that has the highest price.

This will be done once only, as I set a custom post meta key/value each time a variable product has been updated.

The code:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_default_variation_job' );
function set_default_variation_job() {
    if ( ! is_product() || is_admin() ) return;
    
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // Get the variable product object

    if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) return; // Exit if is not a product object

    // Only for variable products & Check if default variation has been updated
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && ! $product->get_meta('_default_variation_updated') ) {

        $active_prices  = $product->get_variation_prices()['price']; // Array of variation Id / active price pairs
        $variations_ids = array_keys($active_prices); // Array of variations IDs
        $variation_id   = end($variations_ids); // Get the variation with the highest price

        $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
        $default_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes(false); // Get formatted variation attributes         
        
        // Set the default variation attributes in the Variable product
        $product->set_default_attributes( $default_attributes );

        // Set a meta data flag to avoid update repetitions
        $product->update_meta_data('_default_variation_updated', '1');
        $product->save(); // Save the data
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).* Tested and works.

Related: [Set the variation with highest discount percentage as Default in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77166832/set-the-variation-with-highest-discount-percentage-as-default-in-woocommerce)

Comment: First of all, thank you for the code. It works!
Secondly, it was my mistake. I didn't copy one segment of your code and ofcourse it didn't  work. My bas. Thank you again. @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 3):

Go to the file `woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`
and add the following line:

```
'selected'   => $options[0],
```

To the function `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()`.
This will pre-select the first variant on the product display page.

Comment: This works but is it possible to do this as a functions.php snippet instead?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm also looking for the opposite (lowest). Is there a way?

Comment: I was looking for this solution and it worked fine for me.