# Set the variation with highest discount percentage as Default in WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I found [Set the highest priced variation as default in WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800869/set-the-highest-priced-variation-as-default-in-woocommerce-variable-products/48803643#48803643) answer code that is working perfectly on my side.

I would like to make some changes: I would like to set the default selected variation with the in stock variation that has the highest discount percentage instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48800869/set-the-highest-priced-variation-as-default-in-woocommerce-variable-products/48803643#48803643), we set the variation with the highest discount percentage that is in stock as the Default selected variation (one time for each variable product).

As a fallback, if there is no variation on sale, we set the highest regular priced (in stock) variation as default.

```php
// Utility function: Get instock variations IDs linked to the variable product
function get_instock_variation_ids( int $parent_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    return $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT pm.post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p.post_parent = {$parent_id} AND pm.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND pm.meta_value = 'instock'
    ");
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'set_default_variation_job2' );
function set_default_variation_job2() {
    if ( ! is_product() || is_admin() ) return;
    
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // Get the variable product object

    if( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) return; // Exit if is not a product object

    // Only for variable products & Check if default variation has been updated
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && ! $product->get_meta('_default_variation_updated') ) {
        $prices      = $product->get_variation_prices(); // Get all variation prices
        $reg_prices  = $prices['regular_price']; // Variations IDs with reg prices
        $sale_prices = $prices['sale_price']; // Variations IDs with sale prices
        $instock_ids = get_instock_variation_ids($product->get_id()); // Get instock variations IDs
        $percentages = array(); // Initializing variable

        // 1st Loop: Loop through variation prices
        foreach ( $sale_prices as $id => $sale_price ) {
            if( ! in_array($id, $instock_ids) ) {
                unset($sale_prices[$id], $reg_prices[$id]); // Remove variations ID / price that aren't instock
            } elseif ( $reg_prices[$id] === $sale_prices[$id] ) {
                 unset($sale_prices[$id]); // Remove variations ID not on sale from "sales prices" array
            }
        }

        // 2nd Loop: Loop through variation sale prices
        foreach ( $sale_prices as $id => $sale_price ) {
            // calculate the saving percentage
            $percentages[$id] = ( $reg_prices[$id] - $sale_prices[$id] ) / $reg_prices[$id] * 100; 
        }
        asort($percentages); // Sort array values in ascending order

        $percentages_ids = array_keys($percentages); // Get the variation Ids from the percentages
        $reg_prices_ids  = array_keys($reg_prices); // Get the variation Ids from the prices

        // Get the variation ID with the highest saving percentage 
        // If no variation on sale, get the variation with hightest price
        $variation_id = count($percentages_ids) > 0 ? end($percentages_ids) : end($reg_prices);

        if ( $variation_id > 0 ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
            $default_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes(false); // Get formatted variation attributes 

            // Set the default variation attributes in the Variable product
            $product->set_default_attributes( $default_attributes );

            // Set a meta data flag to avoid update repetitions
            $product->update_meta_data('_default_variation_updated', '1');
            $product->save(); // Save the data
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

##### Addition 1

###### Updating variation products one time more.

If you make changes to your product variations, like updating prices or stock status, you can use the following function **just one time**.

The function will reset '_default_variation_updated' custom field everywhere, allowing the process to start again one time for all variable products.

Add the following code:

```php
function reset_for_update_set_default_variation_job( $reset ) {
    if ( ! $reset ) return;
    
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm SET meta_value = ''
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '_default_variation_updated'
    " );
}

reset_for_update_set_default_variation_job( true ); // true for activation
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Then browse a page on your website. Once done, replace `true` with `false` like:

```
reset_for_update_set_default_variation_job( false ); // true for activation
```

---

##### Addition 2

###### Make this process active forever.

If you want the process to be active all the time, simply remove:

```
&& ! $product->get_meta('_default_variation_updated')
```

and

```
// Set a meta data flag to avoid update repetitions
$product->update_meta_data('_default_variation_updated', '1');
```

Comment: Tested on my site and found 2 errors:
1. When you have products without sale (simple or variable) it is showing error
2. When you enter 1st time function is working correctly, but when product is updated (changed with price or stock), default variation is not updated. This is important for us as we are changing prices twice per month.

Can you please check this?

Btw is there any way to add function for Sale badge on hole site (home, archive, single product)? Sale badge to show actual sale % of the default variation of the product (not the highest sale % from all variations of product).

Comment: It shows error: What error? on what line?  My code doesn't handle the fact that you update your products often and you didn't mention that in your question. When updating your products, you should also update the default selected variation on your side.

Comment: I have added some additions…